# What's the oddness of statements like "some of them but one failed the exams"?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

If "some of them but one did something" is an odd sentence in english, how could one rephrase it so that it makes sense?

What exactly causes its meaninglessness?

Comment: Why do you think it is odd?

Comment: I was told it is "clearly odd", but I didn't realise why.

Comment: It's meaningless.

Comment: Hot Licks, how could one rephrase it?

Comment: The common phrase would be: "all of them but one".

Comment: @GEdgar got it. _All (NP) but one_ (meaning 'all NP except one') is an idiomatic fixed phrase. *_Some NP but one_ is not an idiom, and doesn't have any obvious meaning -- some of them but not others? some of them but not one (that means _all but one_)?

Comment: All but one of them failed the exams.

Comment: What are you trying to express?

Answer (score 2):

Let’s say there were 100 students.

If 100 students fail, you would say “All the students failed.”

If 99 students fail, you would say “All but one of the students failed.” You have removed one student from the group “all.”

If 50 students fail, you would say “Some of the students failed.” You divided the students into two groups - some passed and some failed.

If you tried to say “some of the students but one failed,” that would mean you divided the students into two groups, but then you moved one student from one group to the other. This makes no sense. Why would you divide the students into two groups, put one student in the wrong group, and then move that student back to the right group?

It’s sort of like saying “Bob and Susie will be group A, and Jon and Chelsea will be group B. But move Bob from group A to group B.” It doesn’t make sense to divide them up incorrectly and then change it, instead of just dividing them up correctly.